# Rails app points to 500.html page when uploaded to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I've created my stack on heroku and everything has been deployed but when I try to actually visit it via URL it just defaults to the 500.html error page.  The app ran fine on my localhost, but I developed it in sqlite3.  I've since changed my Gemfile to look like the following and ran bundle install.

```
#gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'thin'

group :production do
   gem 'pg'
end
group :development, :test do
   gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

When you visit the url it should be pointing to my login page.

This is what my database.yml file looks like...does this have anything to do with my problem.

```
development:
   adapter: sqlite3
   database: db/development.sqlite3
   pool: 5
   timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
   adapter: sqlite3
   database: db/test.sqlite3
   pool: 5
   timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Thanks for any advice

Comment: did you check your logs ? heroku logs -t --app <your_app_name>

Answer (score 1):

Use `heroku logs` to see the log file showing the 500 error's cause.  If you haven't run your migrations that might be the cause.  Be sure to run:

`heroku run rake db:migrate`

before you use your app.

Comment: I ran heroku run db:migrate but haven't checked the logs.  I'll post the results.

Comment: Oops, it's `heroku run rake db:migrate`. Updated the answer. :)

Comment: my logs are very lengthy, but heres a few lines that might pertain to my issue.  Can i get your opinion?

Comment: ?[36m2013-04-02T19:20:00+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m Completed 500 Internal Server Err
or in 178ms

Comment: ?[36m2013-04-02T19:08:42+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gem
s/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:214:in `block in replace_gem
': Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-a
dapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (LoadError)

Comment: That error is referring to a missing `pg` gem. Are you sure you checked in your changes to your Gemfile?

Comment: Yeah i logged into my github account and actually viewed the gemfile to make sure.  And obviously pushed it to heroku.  huh so confused

Comment: Odd... try moving it out of the `group` block into the basic Gemfile as `gem 'pg'`.  It won't hurt, it'll just install the gem in test and dev as well as production. See what that does...

Comment: just finished doing what you suggested and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your database.yml file points to SQLite still.  You'll need to change that to point to the PostgreSQL DB on heroku.

Comment: This might be a redundant question but is how do I change it to point to the PostgreSQL?  Do I just just change "sqlite3" to "pg" or "postgresql"?  And do I have to change the port number?  When it comes to getting a new app live on heroku, I'm a newbie.

Comment: I'm no heroku expert, so I couldn't tell you those specifics. At a minimum, You would change "sqlite3" to "pg", and the database to whatever the Postgres database name is.

Answer (score 0):

I can see from the comment that you are using sqlite for production into heroku. Which is not possible since heroku doesnt support sqlite. You can either use pg or mysql2 for your production environment. You can check here for solution :

[How to configure database.yml for deployment to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864695/how-to-configure-database-yml-for-deployment-to-heroku/27866610#27866610)

And once you are done with it run these commands

```
heroku run rake db:reset
heroku run rake db:drop db:create db:seed
heroku run rake db:migrate
```