# How to configure database.yml for deployment to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku

I recently upgraded to the newest version of Rails, and I don't understand how to deploy applications to Heroku.

Here is my `database.yml` file

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

I have never seen this syntax before in database.yml. Does anyone know how to configure this?

It looks a lot different than what I'm used to

```
development:
 adapter: mysql2
 encoding: utf8
 database: my_app_development
 pool: 5
 username: root
 password:

test:
 adapter: mysql2
 encoding: utf8
 database: my_app_test
 pool: 5
 username: root
 password:


production:
 adapter: mysql2
 encoding: utf8
 database: ymca_gym_production
 pool: 5
 username: root
 password:
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Heroku you will have to use postgresql as it doesn't support mysql2. Heroku has its own mechanism to handle databases which you can read more about here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql

Essentially, treat "heroku's databases" and local databases that you define in this file completely different. It will be easier for you to use sqlite for local and test environments and for production you should change your yaml code to this :

```
development:
 adapter: mysql2
 encoding: utf8
 database: my_app_development
 pool: 5
 username: root
 password:

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
      adapter: postgresql
      database: my_database_production
      pool: 5
      timeout: 5000
```

Above code is not enough to get it working on heroku yet, you will also need to edit the gemfile content like below :

```
gem 'pg', :group => :production
gem 'mysql2' , :group => :development
gem 'sqlite3', :group => :test
```

I have made the gemfile code according to the database.yaml code that i wrote. You can use mysql2 for both development and test environment. If you are doing so you can change the gemfile contents like below:

```
gem 'pg', :group => :production
gem 'mysql2' , :group => [:development, :test]
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: "It will be easier for you to use sqlite for local and test environments" is bad advice. There are subtle differences between the two (i.e. PG string column length limits) that you'll only discover once you deploy your app to the _other_ environment. You generally want your development environment to be as close as possible to your production environment in order to avoid the _it worked on my machine_ class of bugs.

Comment: I myself use PostgreSQL for all the environments. I said so because most people prefer to use sqlite3 since its easy and light weight. :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is exactly what you want, but I just spent a while figuring this out myself, so I thought I'd post it here.

ActiveRecord supports getting database connection information both from the environmental variable `DATABASE_URL` and from the database.yml file. Exactly which one gets used in any situation can be a little tricky. Fortunately, this has already mostly been taken care of - see [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/13582) pull request for most of the details.

The short version is that if there isn't a url key in your database.yml, then the information in `DATABASE_URL` automatically overrides database.yml for everything that it can set that is present in the URL, including username, password, server, port, adapter, and database name. If there is a url key in database.yml, then that overrides the `DATABASE_URL` env var and everything else that it conflicts with in the database.yml entry.

Since Heroku sets a full `DATABASE_URL` automatically, basically everything except for the pool and encoding are taken from that, and entries for the other things in the production section of the database.yml are ignored. So you can leave them blank, or set anything that is more convenient for you on your dev machine.

Since it is possible to put ERB in yml files, [some sources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database) recommend that you explicitly put

```
production:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

in your database.yml to explicitly set the url as the env var. This makes it more clear that whatever is in the env var is meant to override everything in the yml.

Answer (score 0):

in yaml

`<<: *default`

this means that you are appending *default* to the group, so this

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3
```

is equal to this

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  database: db/development.sqlite3
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding some further info to this very old post. Heroku does now (obviously) support MySQL and there are some intricacies in how it handles the databae.yml file. The behaviour depends on the version of Rails you are using, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-database-connection-behavior

If you, like me, are trying to configure certain MySQL parameters and haven't got any luck using the database.yml file because you may be, like me, working on upgrading a very old Rails 3 app then you should know that certain parameters can be appended to the connection string, or `DATABASE_URL`

For example, I needed to configure character collation and encoding and succeeded with this

```
mysql2://dbuser:host.amazonaws.com:3306/dbname?sslca=config/global-bundle.pem&encoding=utf8mb4&collation=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

The sslca parameter points to a SSL bundle file that has been checked into the project repo's config folder. The following 2 parameters are usually added to database.yml.

Maybe this helps someone.